# Google Amp responsive image doesn’t display when wrapped in an anchor tag

Tags: amp-html

I am creating a google amp page and need to include a responsive image. I want the image to be clickable so that when it is clicked it navigates to another url using an anchor tag. Everything works perfectly until I wrap the amp-image with an anchor tag at which point the image will no longer be displayed on the page. If I use some other layout option, such as fixed or flex-item the image appears as it is supposed to even with the anchor tag.

The amp validation test passes.

Here is the html I am submitting:

```
 <a href="www.example.com">
    <amp-img layout="responsive" src="/src/photo.JPG" width="2056" height="396"/></amp-img>
 </a>
```

This is the resulting html that is rendered on the page.

```
  <a href="www.example.com">
    <amp-img layout="responsive" class="-amp-element -amp-layout-responsive -amp-layout-size-defined" src="/src/photo.JPG" width="2056" height="396">
      <i-amp-sizer style="display:block; padding-top: 19.26%"></i-amp-sizer>
    </amp-img>
  </a>
```

Usually after the `i-amp-sizer` tag another img tag is added which is the one that displayed on the page. As you can see, however, when I add an anchor tag that img tag disappears. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening or how to fix it.

Comment: So `amp-img` by itself without the anchor tag appears correctly?

Comment: @thumbtackthief yes that is correct. Even if I surround it with other tags it displays correctly. It's only when I add the anchor tag.

Comment: Interesting:  I'm having a similar problem, but the `a` tag doesn't seem to change anything.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107954/amp-image-is-not-appearing

Comment: Do you have `<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
` in your `head`?

Comment: Yes that script is included, I have been using the amp console validator and it confirms that the AMP page is indeed valid so it has all the necessary boilerplate and tags. Glad to see you solved your problem thought!

Comment: For anyone else like me stumbling across this issue. It maybe that the parent anchor has no width since it's an inline element.

As a result, the "responsive" amp-img child element has zero height/width. This is because the parent anchor is effectively collapsing in.

Potential fixes:
* Set display: block or a fixed width on the parent anchor
* Use layout="fixed" instead of responsive on your amp-img tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my amp-custom css I had `display: inline-block` set for anchor tags. Once I deleted the inline-block style tag it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following was missing under the head tag.

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
```

That work for me.

Comment: Please describe more or consider delete this.

Comment: That's the main AMP js. Without that nothing would work, not just the images wouldn't display. Also the browser addon would immediately alert about this.

Answer (score 0):

Check by adding `display : grid;` CSS on the anchor tag.
In my case, I got the solution by this.