# AMP image is not appearing

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I can't get this `amp-img` to show up.  It works as an image, and when I click the src-link it loads on a separate page correctly.  Changing it to `amp-img` makes it disappear.  I set `background-color: red` on the `amp-img` and the box appears correctly, but it's an empty red box.

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="/">
    <amp-img src="https://d12v9rtnomnebu.cloudfront.net/oursite/logo_white.png" alt="site logo" width="264" height="96"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

CSS (probably a lot of extraneous stuff that needs to be trimmed but don't know what's important until it works):

```
.amp .site-menu li {
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
}

.amp .site-menu li:first-child {
    float: left;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.amp .site-menu a {
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.amp .site-menu amp-img {
    height: 32px;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had left out the `head` tag of `<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>` as listed in the [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec#required-markup).  Including that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code ::

`<amp-img src="https://d12v9rtnomnebu.cloudfront.net/oursite/logo_white.png" alt="site logo" width="264" height="96"></amp-img>`

[Also read here](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/converting/building-page/?format=websites)